# Замена текста скриптом в bash

Tags: скрипт, shell, bash, linux

В переменной $ztag0 содержится HTML код. Необходимо заменить совпадения в HTML коде из переменной $domain на знак "/". Пробовал разные варианты, но работа скрипта завершается ошибками

```
domain="http://www.gym-gym.ru/"
$ztag0 | sed 's/$domain/'/'/g'
```

вывод скрипта:

```
x.sh: 28: x.sh: <a: not found
sed: -e выражение #1, символ 12: неизвестный модификатор к `s'
```

Comment: Как минимум у Вас Хешкод подсветил косяк в аргументах sed.

Comment: первое совпадение не обрабатывается. в файл записать могу, а в переменную записать результат не получается. Пробовал так:

ztag1="echo $ztag0 |  sed -e s,${domain},/,g"

Comment: Надо использовать наклонные кавычки:
    
    ztag1="`echo $ztag0 | sed -e s,${domain},/,g`"

Comment: разобрался. ещё так можно:

ztag1=$(echo $ztag0 |  sed -e s,${domain},/,g) 

Но напомню, первое совпадение не срабатывает. К стати оформите это как ответ, т.к. он уже практически разрешился

Comment: Для записи в переменную используйте обратные кавычки.

    ztag1=`echo $ztag0 | sed s,"$domain",/,g`

В обычные кавычки нужно заключать именно переменную $domain, т.к. если в ней будут пробелы, то все сломается.

И учтите, в ней не должно быть запятых (',').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@shaman888](/users/11102/shaman888) может

```
 sed -e s,${domain},/,g
```

А что означает `$ztag0 |` ? Возможно должно быть

```
echo $ztag0 |  sed -e s,${domain},/,g
```

Comment: $ztag0 ничего не означает, это произвольное название переменной

Comment: @shaman888 а почему первое вхождение не заменяет? Я проверял на единственном (оно же первое)

@avp про запятые и пробелы -- разумеется да. Но разделитель в `s//` может быть разным